# Efficiently reshape an array 2D -> 3D

Tags: julia

I am currently working on datasets where I have 2D matrices / arrays of dimensions `(n,pxq)`. I have to reshape these matrices to obtain a 3D array of size `(n,q,p)`.
At the moment, I am stuck with

```
# Assuming mat2 exists
mat3 = zeros(n,q,p)
for r in 1:n
    mat3[r,:,:] = transpose(reshape(mat2[r,:],p,q))
end
```

Is there a way to avoid this manipulation, or at least to optimize it a bit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reshape`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.reshape) + [`permutedims`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.permutedims):

```
mat3 = permutedims(reshape(mat2, n, p, q), (1, 3, 2))
```